# Plot Error in R: need finite 'ylim' values

Tags: r

I am trying to use functions `between` and `within` to calculate between and (total) within cluster variances for top 2 through 20 clusters defined by Ward's hierarchical clustering. I am getting an error code after plotting the graph.

The error is

**Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'ylim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf**

Here is my code

```
within <- function(whs2018annexBdatscl,clust) {
w <- numeric(length(unique(clust)))
for ( i in sort(unique(clust)) ) {
members <- whs2018annexBdatscl[2==i,,drop=F]
centroid <- apply(members,2,mean)
members.diff <- sweep(members,2,centroid)
w[i] <- sum(members.diff^2)
}
return(w)

between <- function(whs2018annexBdatscl,clust) {
b <- 0
total.mean <- apply(whs2018annexBdatscl,2,mean)
for ( i in sort(unique(clust)) ) {
members <- whs2018annexBdatscl[clust==i,,drop=F]
centroid <- apply(members,2,mean)
b = b + nrow(members)*sum( (centroid-total.mean)^2 )
w[i] <- sum(members.diff^2)
}
return(b)


data.1 <- whs2018annexBdatscl[,apply(whs2018annexBdatscl,2,sd)>1]
dd.1 <- dist(data.1)
hc.ward = hclust(dist(whs2018annexBdatscl), method="ward.D2")
w.tot <- numeric(20)
btw <- numeric(20)
for ( k in 2:20 ) {
clust <- cutree(hc.ward,k=k)
w <- within(data.1,clust)
w.tot[k-1] <- sum(w)
btw[k-1] <- between(data.1,clust)
}
plot(2:20,w.tot[-1],pch=19,type="b",xlab="K")
plot(2:20,btw[-1],pch=19,type="b")
plot(2:20,(btw[-1]/(2:20))/(w.tot[-1]/(nrow(data.1)-2:20)),pch=19,type="b")
```

Please how can I fix this error.

Here is my [dataset](https://cdn.inst-fs-iad-prod.inscloudgate.net/6fba3d1b-3b08-4a56-aef1-cafcfde5c39b/whs2018_AnnexB-subset-wo-NAs.txt?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6ImNkbiJ9.eyJyZXNvdXJjZSI6Ii82ZmJhM2QxYi0zYjA4LTRhNTYtYWVmMS1jYWZjZmRlNWMzOWIvd2hzMjAxOF9Bbm5leEItc3Vic2V0LXdvLU5Bcy50eHQiLCJ0ZW5hbnQiOiJjYW52YXMiLCJ1c2VyX2lkIjoiMTg3NTAwMDAwMDAzNzIyMDkiLCJpYXQiOjE2MTgxMTAzMTIsImV4cCI6MTYxODE5NjcxMn0.7mz-XbxKFZ_g5-UZbOldrJX0ESvom6Zm-rdp8FHJwkemy2XtnK1Y8wZax0PpuyiL2PhWKWHDYuJ0TBt1aC3g8w&content_type=text%2Fplain)

Comment: Isn't this wrong: `whs2018annexBdatscl[2==i,,drop=F]`? It will only subset the 2nd row.

Comment: Thank you @RuiBarradas. I updated the code. Here is the new error code I got. I think I need to eliminate non-numeric rows in my data. How can I do that? Error in if (is.na(n) || n > 65536L) stop("size cannot be NA nor exceed 65536") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: You are mssing `}` after each `return`.

Comment: Sorry @RuiBarradas. I have it in my code. I did not include it in what I pasted. I will update.

Comment: The error message that I have now is: Error in if (is.na(n) || n > 65536L) stop("size cannot be NA nor exceed 65536") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed